# Enter standard input for values of map

Tags: c++, input, dictionary

I'm trying to write a map that takes in an integer as the key and then an x amount of int values that are given to it via standard input. This is my first time working with maps so I'm running into several issues and was wondering if someone could help understand better what I am doing incorrectly. Normally with a vector/array the following would work fine:

```
int standardInput;
for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
    cin standardInput;
    array[i] = standardInput;
}
```

I can't get that to work similarly when using a map:

```
int numberToCompare = 4;
map<int numberToCompare, int>myMap;
    int standardInput;
    cout << "Enter numbers: " << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cin standardInput;
        myMap.insert(standardInput);
    }
```

I'm still trying to understand about the key and values. The way I understood when reading about maps was that with a map the key is unique unlike multi maps. What I don't know how to do is allow user input to fill the rest of the map. I saw lots of examples online where inside the code people manually entered all of the input doing the following (this goes against what I want to accomplish).

```
portMap_.insert(pair<string,int>("fourth", 4444)); 
portMap_.insert(pair<string,int>("fifth", 5555));
```

EDIT: To clarify in case I caused some confusion, I'm trying to fill a map with numbers that are given via standard input.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what it is you want to do?

Comment: @melak47 Pretty much just trying to fill the map with numbers given by using cin. What I wrote above would work fine to fill an array/vector but I don't know how to do that for a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you browse the documentation for `std::map` found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/). Then take a look at the examples provided in the `insert()` method documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/).

The declare a `map` object, you need to specify the type for the key and the type for the value by providing the type name as template parameters:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int,int> myMap;
```

If you then want to insert a key/value pair:

```
int myKey = 10;
int myVal = 100;
myMap.insert(pair<int,int>(myKey, myVal));
```

The above can be made a bit more terse with some typedefs:

```
typedef map<int,int> IntMap;
typedef pair<int,int> IntPair;

IntMap myMap;
myMap.insert(IntPair(10, 100));
```

If you want the key/value pairs to be provided by user input, just write a simple loop that accepts the values from standard input and insert the values into your map.

There are plenty of resources here for reading values from standard input. Something like the below would do the trick:

```
// pseudo-code
while (did the user quit?)
{
    int key   = 0;
    int value = 0;

    cin >> key >> value;

    // maybe if the user enters -1, then you quit, otherwise:

    myMap.insert(pair<int,int>(key, value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    map<int, string> m;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        string s = "abracadabra";
        m.insert(pair<int, string>(i, s));
    }
    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second <<"\n";
    }
}
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:write a map that takes in an integer as the key and then an x amount of int values that are given to it via standard input

**Solution** Here i provided the code which will take the std input and store it to the MAP, 
enter code here

```
`#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int key;
    long x;
    cin >> n;//std input for number of entries in to MAP
    map <int, long> map_book;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> x;//std input for VALUE
        cin >> key;//std input for KEY
        map_book[key] = x;
    }

    //here am searching the x and pinting if it is there in MAP or Else priniting it is not found
    while(cin >> x) {
        if (map_book.find(x) != map_book.end()) {
            cout << x << "=" << map_book.find(x)->second << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    map<char,int>mp;
    char a;
    int b,n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>a>>b;
        mp.insert(pair<char,int>(a,b));
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(auto&x:mp)
    {
        cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
3
a 1
b 2
c 3

a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> first;

  first['x']=8;
  first['y']=16;
  first['z']=32;

  for(map<char,int>::iterator it = first.begin(); it != first.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first <<" "<< it->second<<endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```